# Writing to cloud DB2 table using pyspark

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, db2, append, etl

I have just started my ETL journey using pyspark. My current goal is to write data from a .csv to a dashdb using append mode. However, I ran into an issue I can't seem to solve. Here's what I've done so far:

I've read the .csv and registered it into a temp table to be able to call SQL queries on it. The output of the query is the following:

```
+--------------------+--------+-------+-----+------+
|              Street|District|Area_m2|Rooms| Price|
+--------------------+--------+-------+-----+------+
|          Angyalföld|    XIII|    105|    2|320000|
|            Belváros|       V|     70|    2|230000|
|         Pozsonyi út|    XIII|     89|    2|290000|
|         Fecske utca|    VIII|     33|    1|130000|
|Margó Tivadar utc...|   XVIII|     80|    2|220000|
|      Orczy út 46-48|    VIII|     44|    2|120000|
|        Vaskapu utca|      IX|     51|1 + 1|185000|
|       Gubacsi út 19|      IX|     30|    1|105000|
|         Öv utca 133|     XIV|     29|    1|150000|
|         Mérleg utca|       V|     54|    2|190000|
|          Szirtes út|       I|    160|    4|389000|
|       Gubacsi út 19|      IX|     50|    2|130000|
|          Török utca|      II|     53|1 + 1|165000|
|          Ferenc tér|      IX|     65|    2|235000|
|       Kiscelli utca|     III|     34|    1|190000|
|     Dózsa György út|     VII|     47|1 + 1|130000|
|         Vadász utca|       V|     60|1 + 1|185000|
|      István utca 7.|     VII|     30|    1|120000|
|          Regős utca|      XI|     53|    2|180000|
|      Országház utca|       I|    122|    3|680000|
+--------------------+--------+-------+-----+------+
```

The columns in the db2 table have the following types: varchar(50), varchar(10), integer, varchar(10), integer.
I stored the output in a variable and used the following code to write to the dashdb:

`output.write.jdbc(jdbc_url, table, properties = connection_properties, mode = 'append')`

Running this code produces the following error message:

```
An error occurred while calling o310.jdbc.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 11, localhost, executor driver): com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.BatchUpdateException: [jcc][t4][102][10040][3.62.56] Batch failure.  The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member of the batch.
Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements. ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:404)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.o.a(o.java:381)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.a(kn.java:4523)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.c(kn.java:4294)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.executeBatch(kn.java:2600)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:667)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:834)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:834)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: Error for batch element #66: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.62.56
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:668)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:60)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:127)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:481)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:70)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(q.java:57)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.a(sb.java:225)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.a(kn.java:3083)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.d(kn.java:5019)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.a(kn.java:4466)
        ... 17 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.saveTable(JdbcUtils.scala:834)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:515)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.BatchUpdateException: [jcc][t4][102][10040][3.62.56] Batch failure.  The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member of the batch.
Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements. ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:404)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.o.a(o.java:381)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.a(kn.java:4523)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.c(kn.java:4294)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.executeBatch(kn.java:2600)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:667)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:834)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:834)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
    Suppressed: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: Error for batch element #66: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.62.56
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:668)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:60)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:127)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:481)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:70)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(q.java:57)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.a(sb.java:225)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.a(kn.java:3083)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.d(kn.java:5019)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.a(kn.java:4466)
        ... 17 more
```

Can someone please explain what went wrong and how can the issue be solved?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The message is telling you that the batch failed because Db2 returned exception SQL0302N  The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement  is out of range for its corresponding use. Read: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic2.html#sql0302n  . Probably your code causes some unnecessary or incorrect type conversions. Is your source database Db2 on-prem, and your target database in cloud(dashdb?)? Other ways exist to lift the data to cloud...

Comment: hi mao! Thanks for your reply. The source is a .csv file I put together from a pandas dataframe. The target is in cloud. The project is to use pyspark to load the initial data to dashdb and then have another script to do CDC comparing the current data on dashdb table with data from source and add inserts, updates and deletes. This script would just do the initial load of the data to dashdb and the role of it is more of a proof of concept.. I'm open for other solution that use pyspark to load the data to a dashdb

Comment: EDIT your question to give details:  what operating system runs pyspark? Ensure your job that connects to Db2 is configured for unicode/utf-8 .  You are using a *very old* jdbc3 driver dating from v9.7 fp4.  Consider using a current jdbc4 driver, get from https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads , or from your local DBA if you have one.

Comment: I run pyspark from Windows 10. Thanks for the advice, I changed the jdbc driver. However, the issue still sustains. I checked SQL0302N and changed my output query to cast each column according to the DDL in the dashdb. Still no luck.
This is the how i specified my query:
output =  spark.sql('SELECT CAST(STREET AS VARCHAR(50)) as STREET, CAST(DISTRICT AS VARCHAR(10)) AS DISTRICT, CAST(AREA_M2 AS INTEGER) AS AREA_M2, CAST(ROOMS AS VARCHAR(10)) as ROOMS, CAST(PRICE AS INTEGER) AS PRICE from BP_real_estate')

Comment: @mao The issue was solved by removing the accented characters from the STREET column. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be solved by ensuring utf-8 encoding for the .csv and by removing special characters.

Comment: I got the same error while appending the data from Scala / Spark to db2 table. Any help would be appreciated.